# Empty Cart in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

creating new quote on page reload when empty cart in magento2

I have add a item in cart.....after that remove that item from cart.Now I'm reloading cart page ,it creating a new quote for every page reload when empty cart.

How to fixed new quote creating issue when cart empty in magento2

Comment: Are you using localhost in base url like http://localhost?

Comment: Yes... .........

Comment: Use ip address 127.0.0.1 insteadof localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps If you are running magento 2 in local system

Go to Admin Store -> Setting -> Configuration-> Web ->Base URLs

Change localhost to 127.0.0.1 on Base Url. 
Then it solved the problem.

Comment: Can u explain for that issue ...@Hari

Comment: Magento 2 cannot work properly in single domain name, like http://localhost/, http://testsite/, http://magento2site/ etc, So use ip address or domainname like 'http://testsite.local/', also magento 2 returns null for $.mage.cookies.get('form_key'); when using localhost

Comment: Form key issue is the main reason for create new quote in localhost domain?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I changed the base url localhost to ipaddress.still create a new quote for every reload empty cart page

Comment: Minicart still have item?